# How to get macOS Catalina virtual disk?

Tags: macos, extract, virtual-disk

I want to create a Mac virtual machine in VirtualBox on Windows 7. Apple gives you the option to download the beta version of their last operating system which is macOS Catalina for free from here:

https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/redemption#macos

I clicked on "Download the macOS Public Beta Access Utility" and I got macOSPublicBetaAccessUtility.dmg file I extracted it with 7-Zip File Manager and the only file I got form the extraction was macOSPublicBetaAccessUtility.pkg something that VirtualBox doesn't accept when wanting to create Mac Virtual Machine. I want to know if the problem was that I clicked "Download the macOS Public Beta Access Utility" button for getting the virtual macOS disk or 7-Zip File Manager didn't do his job properly?

Comment: Give up now. Getting the beta redemption cert or installer .pkg is not going to get you the install on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: I thought one of the reasons Apple release these beta versions is to be tested on a virtual machine on Windows.

Comment: errmmm… **no**. There is & has never been any licensing for non-Apple hardware, period. You cannot officially get any VM installation on Windows that can run macOS. There are no official guest additions for any VM on Windows to run macOS. Apple releases private & public beta versions of upcoming OS releases to be tested on Apple hardware, nothing else.

Comment: So it is ilegal to try to install it on Windows?

Comment: 'illegal' would have to be decided by a court & no-one has yet tested it. It is against Apple's EULA, which makes it 'legally' the same as installing Windows with a fake key, or a pirate copy.

Comment: I wanted to have a Mac computer only to practise creating iOS applications and a friend of mine told me: "If you need it only for practising why don't you create Mac Virtual Machine on Windows" , I asked him: "But isn't that illegal?" he told me: "it is not lisenced , but if it's not for economic purposes it is OK". But it looks like if it is not licensed you have to make some hacks to make it work on Windows something which it seems Apple doesn't like which means is morally wrong.

Comment: Not licensed/not legal/morally wrong - if you can pass for 19 but drink at age 17 really nothing gets 'broken' irreparably, but... to follow the analogy through… you'd have to come up with your own, convincing, 'fake ID' to get either macOS or beer.

Comment: macOS is not free software; it is a *free bonus provided with Macintosh computers, as an incentive to buy Mac computers*. Allowing it to be installed on non-Mac computers would defeat that purpose, so Apple tries to keep you from doing that, with both technical obstacles (e.g. providing the installer in a non-Windows-compatible form) and legal prohibitions (e.g. the EULA).